# Navigation Bar Width Wrong - Different Browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my CSS / HTML navigation bar.  I am currently on Mac and using safari and the navigation works perfectly.  However when I open it inside of Chrome/Firefox/IE the border isn't sitting the entire length of the navigation bar.

You can see the nav here: http://www.tkdqld.xeonweb.com.au

It is probably something silly within my CSS.  My CSS is below

```css
#nav {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    width:1155px;
    height: 36px;
    margin:auto;
}

#nav ul {
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
}

/* 1 Level Horizontal Nav */

#nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    height:36px;
    padding-right:43px;
    padding-left:42px;
    position:relative;
    border-right:solid 1px #FEE697;
    border-left:solid 1px #FEE697;
}


#nav li a, #nav li a:link {
    font-family: 'SommetRoundedBold',"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    height:35px;
    font-size: 18px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 9px 0px 0px 0px;
    color:black;

}

#nav ul li:hover {
    background:#F0E68C;
    height:35px;
    width:auto;

}

#nav ul li.current {
    background:#5A1416;

}
```

Thanks to anyone who could kindly help me it would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a static left and right padding for each. Fonts render slightly different in different browsers. Try a fixed width for each. Also added a rule to clean up your borders.

```
#nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 36px;
    position: relative;
    border-right: solid 1px #FEE697;
    padding-top: 1px;
    width: 164px;
}

#nav ul li:last-child {
    border-style: none;
}
```

Comment: May I also ask one other thing? The nav bar on that page on the left hand side next to home it sticks our probably 1 or 2 px more then the background.  Any idea what would cause that?

Comment: The width on #header and #nav are slightly too wide.